# Disable swipe navigation on Android Webview through CapacitorJS?

Tags: android, android-webview, capacitor

I've build an Android app using [CapacitorJS](https://capacitorjs.com/) and I want to disable the native webview's swipe navigation (swipe from edges to go forward/back). Is that possible?

Can this be done through Javascript or an HTML meta tag? As far as I can tell this is not possible.

Is there a Capacitor plugin or setting to do this? ([Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/), which uses Capacitor, has the `swipeBackEnabled` setting that sounds like it does what I'm looking for)

If not, can it be set on the Android [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) directly?